# Tools to intercept and tamper SSL/TLS communication

Tags: open-source, ssl

I use wireshark to intercept and analyse network protocols, I also use burpsuit to intercept and temper HTTP/HTTPS requests. Is there a similar tool for SSL/TLS communications? Not only do I want to intercept the SSL/TLS I also want to change it and see what happens.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not fully clear to me what you want. To you want to intercept HTTPS similar to HTTP (can be done with Burpsuite, mitmproxy...) or do you want to fiddle with the TLS handshake itself (i.e. ciphers, extensions, protocol version...)?

Comment: The second one. the ciphers, etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out TLS-ATTACKER (https://github.com/RUB-NDS/TLS-Attacker) developed by the Ruhr University Bochum

It is able to send arbitrary protocol messages in an arbitrary order to the TLS peer, and define their modifications using a provided interface...

Comment: Thanks, bro. I though there would be more tools for this purpose, as it is important for security researchers.